# Let $B=A+t\vec{AC}$ with $t\ne1$, show that $A=B+s\vec{BC}$ for $s=t/(t-1)$

Tags: geometry, vectors, affine-geometry

I have to prove the following:

> Let $B=A+t\vec{AC}$. Let $t:=(A, B, C)=\frac{\vec{AB}}{\vec{AC}}$. Prove that $(B, A, C)=\frac{t}{t-1}$.

I've been trying by two different ways but I always obtain the same result. Here's my attempt:

> We have $(A, B, C)=t$. $$(A, B, C) \implies B=A+t\vec{AC},$$
>
> so
>
> $$(B, A, C) \implies A=B+t\vec{BC}.$$
>
> From here:
>
> $A=B+t\vec{BC} \implies A=A+\vec{AB}+t\vec{BC} \implies \vec{0}=\vec{AB}+t\vec{BC} \implies \vec{BA}=t\vec{BC} \implies t=\frac{\vec{BA}}{\vec{BC}}=(B, A, C).$

But this is not what I wanted. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You are using the hypothesis that $t=(B,A,C)$ (just after "so") while this is not a hypothesis (and actually you should show that $(B,A,C)=t/(t-1)$).

Comment: For my information, who is using notations such as $$\frac{\vec{AB}}{\vec{AC}}\ ?$$

Comment: @Did My professor. It's exactly how he wrote it on the blackboard.

$A, B$ and $C$ are points.

Comment: Sorry to be nosy but this is the first time I hear about this notation so, where is you professor teaching and does he support his notational choices by a book or something?

Comment: @Did He just write things down on the blackboard while he explains. He doesn't follow any book.

Comment: OK. For your information, nobody uses this notation and, especially in a didactical context, to suggest that one divides vectors by vectors would not be an idea supported by many people. All the more so that instead of $t=\vec{AB}/\vec{AC}$ one can use the entirely standard $\vec{AB}=t\cdot\vec{AC}$. (Never saw the notation $(A,B,C)$ to denote the real number $t$ such that $\vec{AB}=t\cdot\vec{AC}$, either, but this notation is not as problematic as the other one, just nonstandard.)

Comment: @Did I'll have in my mind while taking notes. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I deduce from your question correctly, $s = (B, A, C)$ is the number defined by 
$$ A = B + s\def\v{\overrightarrow}\v{BC} \tag 1$$
or $$ \v{BA} = s\v{BC}\tag{1'} $$
We now that 
$$ B = A + t\v{AC} \iff \v{AB} = t\v{AC} \tag 2 $$
Starting with (1'), we have 
\begin{align*}
  s\v{BC} &= \v{BA}\\
  \iff s\v{BA} + s\v{AC} &= \v{BA}\\
  \iff (1-s)\v{BA} &= s\v{AC}\\
  \iff (s-1)\v{AB} &= s\v{AC}\\
  \stackrel{(2)}\iff (s-1)t\v{AC} &= s\v{AC}\\
  \stackrel{\v{AC} \ne 0}\iff (s-1)t &= s\\
    \iff s = \frac{t}{t-1} 
\end{align*}
So if $\v{AC} \ne 0$, we must have $s = \frac{t}{t-1}$.